# Basis and Subbasis verification

Tags: general-topology

Suppose I have a set $X = \{a,b\}$ and the topology $T = \{\{a,b\},\{a\},\{b\},\{0\}\}$ where $0$ is the empty set. Then a basis for the topology $T$ is $\{\{a,b\},\{b\}, \{a\}\}$ and also the subbasis is $\{\{a\},\{b\}\}$. Is any of this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, that's fine, though the basis doesn't actually need the full space included since $X=\{a\}\cup \{b\}$